# gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 error on GCP while training with GCMLE

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Can you please tell me what does this error mean ?

gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement google-gax<0.16dev,>=0.15.7, but you'll have google-gax 0.12.5 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

You have an older version of google-gax.

To update you can run:

```
npm update -g google-gax
```

To install the latest version you can run:

```
npm install google-gax
```